# Needing to double click EditText for click listener to respond

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, onclicklistener, settext

I have a section of code where I want to change the text showing in a textView when the user selects an EditText box.

The problem I am having is that the textView only changes when I double click the EditText box, one click and there is no change to the textView.

Is there another click listener that I should be using?

```
final EditText box0105 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.box0105);
final TextView txtHint = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtHint);
        box0105.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            txtHint.setText(onOneClick);                
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting `OnTouchListener` rather than `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 28):

Add `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in EditText xml then EditText will accept single click

Comment: focusableInTouchMode = "false" achieves the outcome, but it also removes the ability for the user to use the editText (I think?)

Using the onTouchListener accepts single click but also maintains editability of the editText

Comment: @Kurt : no it will not removes the ability for user to use Edittext it just avoid first touch event.

Comment: How this answer got 20 upvotes I will never understand.

Answer (score 5):

use this, it will fire very first.

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 
        @Override 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction())
                // Do whatever you want to do man, but don't trouble your mother
            return false; 
        } 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

set your `edittext` in  `xml`

```
<EditText
  android:focusable="false"
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I set up 2 listeners one is OnClick and another one is OnFocusChange. Like this:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        System.out.println("Edittext has been clicked");
    }
});

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        System.out.println("Edittext has been clicked");
    }
});
```

OnFocus is called when the Edittext is clicked first time and then for all other times OnClick is called.